# calculate sub total and total jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with fields like invoice Quantity, Unit Price and Sub total. I want to loop through and get sub total of each input field and finally get sum of sub total. How can I do that on JQuery? Thanks.

My code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    var sub_total = 0;
     $("#items .targetfields").each(function() {
         var qty = parseInt($("#quantity").val());
         var rate = parseInt($("#rate").val());
         $(".subtotal").val(qty * rate);
     });
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here and explain what you tried and what problem you are having

Comment: I guess you could be doing wrong with the use of `ids` in your selectors. `ids` have to be unique in your whole html document, otherwise you might get unexpected results when querying them.

Comment: can you post the relevant HTML also

Comment: $(document).keyup(function(event) {
  var sub_total = 0;
  $("#items .targetfields").each(function(){    
    var qty = parseInt($("#quantity").val());
    var rate = parseInt($("#rate").val());
    $(".subtotal").val(qty * rate);
  });
  
});

Comment: <tr>
       
        <td><input type="text" nam="quantity" id="quantity"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" nam="rate" id="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" nam="sub_total" id="item_input" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        
        <td><input type="text" nam="quantity" id="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" nam="rate" id="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" nam="sub_total" id="item_input" /></td>
      </tr>

Answer (score 3):

I fixed some of your html (never use duplicate ids)

```
<table id="items">
    <tr class="targetfields"> 
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" class="subtotal" /></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr class="targetfields"> 
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" class="subtotal" /></td> 
    </tr> 
</table>

total: <span id="total"></span>
​
```

​

And here's the js

```
$(function() {

    $("#items").keyup(function(event) {
     var total = 0;
     $("#items .targetfields").each(function() {
         var qty = parseInt($(this).find(".quantity").val());
         var rate = parseInt($(this).find(".rate").val());
         var subtotal = qty * rate;
         $(this).find(".subtotal").val(subtotal);
         if(!isNaN(subtotal))
             total+=subtotal;
     });
     $("#total").html(total);
    });

})​
```

[see it live here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaMRQ/9/)

Comment: duplicate names are not really that much better if the form could ever be sent to the server

Comment: You are right. I focused on fixing the duplicate id problem which was making jquery fail, while duplicate names are legal after all